# Django Rest Framework - 'User' object has no attribute 'payments'

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have been spending quite a lot of time trying to understand this error I got.

From models.py

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, default="")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, default="")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, default="")
    bsb = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    account = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sign_up_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Payment(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="payments")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, default="")
    bsb = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    account = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    paid_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=36500))
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and from serializers.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Payment, Company


class PaymentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='company.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Payment
        fields = ['company', 'name', 'bsb', 'account', 'created_date', 'paid_date', 'status']


class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    payments = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Payment.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ["name", "email", "password", "payments",
                  "bsb", "account", "sign_up_date"]
```

As you can see, I have included the related_name as "payments" for company attribute in Payment class. But when I go to http://localhost:8000/bill_payer/resources/company I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'payments'
```

I have verified that my Company class do indeed have the payments class through manage.py shell.

Any idea? I am new. Here's views.py in case it is important:

```py
class PaymentList(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get(self, request):
        payments = Payment.objects.all()
        serializer = PaymentSerializer(payments, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(company=self.request.user)


class PaymentDetail(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Payment.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Payment.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk):
        payment = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = PaymentSerializer(payment)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk):
        payment = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = PaymentSerializer(payment, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        payment = self.get_object(pk)
        payment.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)


class CompanyList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer


class CompanyDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you try to use User objects for CompanySerializer which expects Company model objects. It will work if you fix it as below.

```
class CompanyList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer


class CompanyDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
```

Comment: Thank you for the extremely fast reply! The reason I'm using User is because I am following this tutorial: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/. I believe the User is part of from django.contrib.auth.models import User. Do you know why they used User and what is the advantage of it? Thanks again, you're the best.

Comment: You're welcome! The example in the link proceeds through the User model and its is given in the Meta class of UserSerializer. This is actually a different situation than your example. If you wanted to use a UserListView or UserDetailView, you should have done this. But you want to do this for Company, which is a completely different model.

Answer (score 0):

Please change this

```
class CompanyList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer


class CompanyDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
```

to

```
class CompanyList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer


class CompanyDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
```

also your doing wrong here in perform_create method.

```
class PaymentList(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get(self, request):
        payments = Payment.objects.all()
        serializer = PaymentSerializer(payments, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(company=self.request.user)
```

it should not be

```
serializer.save(company=self.request.user)
```

coz its not a company object. self.request.user is a user object. And you are trying to save user object to company object. its wrong.
try using

```
serializer.save()
or
serializer.save(company=serializer.data.get("company"))
```

Comment: Hi @jeevu94, I think perform_create method helps create Payment object with a company field that is implicitly mentioned in the URL. Maybe you can correct me on that? Here is the reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/

Comment: yes it helps. but the variable you are passing its not correct.
eg: if that would be 
`serializer.save(user=self.request.user)`
it was fine. but you are passing 
`(company=self.request.user)
(company obj != user obj)` 
did you get it?

for your project just use
`serializer.save()`

Comment: no need of perform_create method. it'll done automatically by serializer.
only edit it if you want to do some coding before saving.
if not just use serializer.save() in you view code. thats it.